# Find overall rank of a MySQL record and determine if tied

Tags: php, mysql, rank

I using the following code to retrieve a player's overall ranking in 6 categories (Games Played, Goals, Assists, etc....)
The code works well and either produces the overall rank, or if the player is tied with another player, adds a "T-" before the rank (i.e. "Ranked 152nd" or "Ranked T-152nd").

Assume that the player's stats have already been queried, in this case, stored as $GP_total.

```
$get_GP_rk = $pdo -> prepare("SELECT GP FROM player_career WHERE GP>=:GP_total");
$get_GP_rk -> bindParam(':GP_total',$GP_total);
$get_GP_rk -> execute();

$result_GP_rk = $get_GP_rk -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
$tie_GP_rk = array_count_values($result_GP_rk);

if ($tie_GP_rk[$GP_tot] == 1){
    $GP_rk = $get_GP_rk -> rowCount();
}
else {
    $GP_rk = "T-".(($get_GP_rk -> rowCount())-($tie_GP_rk[$GP_tot]-1));
}
```

My problem is that I use this exact block of code 6 times and this is slowing down my page load time considerably.

Is there a faster/more streamlined way to achieve this?
Simply put, I need the following for 6 fields:

1) the player's value

2) how many people have more than him

3) if he is tied with anyone

Thanks in advance!

EDIT***
Sample table structure

```
ID    GP    Goals    Assists    Points    Penalties    Shots
101   36    14       12         26        8            36
102   25    9        17         26        2            59
103   8     1        5          6         0            12
```

Comment: Why exactly you are using it 6 times

Comment: To find the player's ranking in EACH of the six categories (games, goals, assists, points, penalties, etc...)

Comment: Fetch all the records once ad do the calculations in your php

Comment: Wouldn't this take longer? Imagine the player ranked 300th in all categories. The query array would contain 1800 results across the 6 categories.

Comment: ca you post ur table structure

Comment: So `id` is `player id` ?

Comment: @Strawberry - Yes. This query shows up on the INDIVIDUAL player's page. So on player 102's page, you would have all his stats, and where he ranks in each category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here's one idea - but you'll need to say a little bit more about how you want to handle ties...

```
SELECT x.*
     , COUNT(*) rank
  FROM (

SELECT  player_id, 'GP' stat, GP score FROM stats
UNION
SELECT  player_id, 'Goals', Goals FROM stats
UNION
SELECT  player_id, 'Assists', Assists FROM stats
UNION
SELECT  player_id, 'Points', Points FROM stats
UNION
SELECT  player_id, 'Penalties', Penalties FROM stats
UNION
SELECT  player_id, 'Shots', Shots FROM stats

) x

JOIN (

SELECT  player_id, 'GP' stat, GP score FROM stats
UNION
SELECT  player_id, 'Goals', Goals FROM stats
UNION
SELECT  player_id, 'Assists', Assists FROM stats
UNION
SELECT  player_id, 'Points', Points FROM stats
UNION
SELECT  player_id, 'Penalties', Penalties FROM stats
UNION
SELECT  player_id, 'Shots', Shots FROM stats

) y
ON y.stat = x.stat
AND y.score >= x.score
GROUP BY stat,score,player_id ORDER BY stat,rank;
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using a variation of this solution to create a mysql view, while dealing with ties via PHP.